# Why web service not called if I change return type in signature?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I created asp.net web service and I call it with help of jquery ajax.

Here is jquery ajax method:

```
  $.ajax( {         
      type: "POST",     
      url: "../../Search/Address.aspx/Search2",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json", 
      data: '{ txtStreet:"'+ "bronson str." +'"}', 
      success: function( data ) {
       alert(data)
       //response(data.d);
      },
       error: function (error) {
         alert("error")
        }
    }) ;
```

and I have this asp.net web service:

```
public partial class Address : Page
{
    //some enother  functions and events.

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute]
    public static string[] Search2(string txtStreet) 
    {
        return new String[] { "Foo1", "Foo2", "Foo3" }; ;
    }
}
```

The service above works fine!

If in service above I change return type in signature it's not called:

```
public partial class Address : Page
{
    //some enother  functions and events.

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute]
    public static string Search2(string txtStreet) 
    {
        return "Foo1";
    }
}
```

Any idea why service not called when I change return type in signature?

Comment: You are using `dataType: "json", `, Is "Foo1" a valid JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jquery you have set dataType as "Json" and in webservice you are returning string. Pass a valid json if you want to set datatype as json in ajax call.

Comment: Just remove dataType: "json" in ajax call and return "Foo1" in webservice function.

Comment: @Michael did this work for you?  Did you check if the server-side method was being called (by putting a break-point on the method)?  According to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ the wrong datatype should give an error, not fail to call the service ("service not called").

Answer (score 2):

The above code should be working and here is a sample of mine that worked:

```
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtValue").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "GetJsonData.aspx/GetValue",
                        data: "{'value':'" + $("#txtValue").val() + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="txtValue" />
</div>
```

**Web Method**:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetValue(string value)
{
   return ("Foo1");
}
```

Or

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute]
 public static string GetValue(string value)
 {
    return ("Foo1");
 }
```